# Create service principal from azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to create a service principal from azure cli.

```
az login --service-principal -u servicePrincipalGuid -p spPassword --tenant tenantGuid

az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment
```

It works if i assign to the service principal Global administrator but it does not work with the Application Administration which according to the documentations should be sufficient.

I am wondering what roles/permissions  are needed to be able to create a service principal without global administrator?

Comment: this might be due to how the azure cli implemented the API calls. if you do this through the API directly application administration would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it is really weird, based on my knowledge, the `Application administrator` role should work.

[image]

The command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment` creates the app registration successfully, but it can't create the corresponding service principal. Even if I test with the command below to create service principal for the app.

```
az ad sp create --id '<object-id of the app registration>'
```

or powershell

```
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId <object-id of the app registration>
```

> I am wondering what roles/permissions are needed to be able to create a service principal without global administrator?

If you just want to let the command work without the global admin, you could add `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission of `Azure Active Directory Graph` like below, then it will work.

[image]

[image]